# Using BibTool with Regular Expressions to fix Double Bracketed Entries

Tags: bibtool

My `.bib` file has a number of entries in the `Title` field which are double bracketed. This preserves lower-case letters in the title which I don't want. I want my bibliography style to sort out the capitalization. Here's an abbreviated entry which illustrates the problem.

```
@Article{     Widerker2013,
  Author    = {Widerker, D. and Goetz, S.},
  Title     = {{Fischer against the dilemma defence: the defence
          prevails}}
}
```

What I'm trying to get is something like this:

```
@Article{     Widerker2013,
  Author    = {Widerker, D. and Goetz, S.},
  Title     = {Fischer against the dilemma defence: the defence
          prevails},
}
```

I have been using BibTool's `rewrite.rule` command to try and fix this. I've been using regular expressions to specify the desired output format. But it's not working and I have no idea why. Here is the command I've been using in a `.rsc` file.

```
rewrite.rule { Title # "^\{\{(.*)\}\}$" # "^\{\1\}$" }
```

Running BibTool with this command doesn't return an error. But it also seems to do absolutely nothing. The `Title` field is exactly the same.

I have been running BibTool in a directory on my desktop, but I can't imagine that's the source of the problem. Here's what I'm doing in the command line:

```
./bibtool -r lib/myresource -i old.bib -o new.bib
```

What gives?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact flavour of RegEx `bibtool` uses, but are you sure about the `$` in `\{(.$)\}`?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @meowe Good call on the `$`. I mistyped. I intended `*`. I changed the mistake in the original post. 

@Bobyandbob This is primarily a BibLaTeX question. I'm using the software BibTool on a `.bib` file in order to clean up the bibliography. I'm not typesetting anything - there is no PDF output, nor do I ever run `pdflatex` in the process. I input a `.bib` and output a `.bib`. So, I'm not sure how to respond to your request for more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Biber and its tool mode instead of bibtool (which I have never used).

Create a file called `stripbraces.conf` with the contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" level="user">
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_source="title" map_match="\A\{(.*)\}\Z" map_replace="$1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

in the same directory as your `.bib` file.

Then run

```
biber --tool --configfile=stripbraces.conf <yourbibfile>.bib
```

Biber will then process the `.bib` file and produce a file called `<yourbibfile>_bibertool.bib` in which the braces of title fields have been stripped.

The regular expression `\A\{(.*)\}\Z` might be too eager in some cases, so could try `\A\{([^\}\{]*)\}\Z` which is not eager enough in some cases.

Comment: This did the trick. I tried the "less eager" regular expression string you suggested first, and that didn't work. But the Biber fix solved the issue. Thanks!